Installing NVIDIA 390 via run file on Kubuntu 24.04
I've been running Kubuntu 24.04 on my (11-year-old) laptop with the Nvidia GeForce GT 720M which has to be used with Optimus.
Results of lspci :
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 720M
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

By the way, ubuntu-drivers devices doesn't give me any other choice, and sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 just does not work.
I have since followed this guide by inttf, completely skipping the warning for Optimus hardware. Since my driver is also quite old, I had to use their driver patch for newer kernels. It went fine, except for the part that my screen had almost completely blackened out, rendering only my precious mouse pointer. Thankfully the driver did actually load that time, so I knew that I had actually "succeeded".

This is the part where I realized that my GPU actually used Optimus, and I had to revert to the Nouveau drivers, which is not satisfactory. I want to see if there is any other way to install this driver version, since Nvidia has dropped support for my GPU.

See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2500877  Looks like 22.04 is the last LTS release offering the (unsupported) 390.

https://launchpad.net/~dtl131/+archive/ubuntu/nv390test

I have exactly the same issue with my Asus UX32VD which has a Nvidia GT 620M.
For now I gave up and use only intel graphic but it's a shame.
